# Adding a column in a DataFrame based on thresholds and size of group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with x and y coordinates, where the index represents a timestamp. We may assume it is an object that moves every timestep. The distance between consecutive timestamps is expected to increase. However, if the distance doesn't increase by a certain threshold, I consider it a potential "waiting" position.
I use the word potential, because the data is quite noisy, and a single 'waiting' condition is not enough to be really sure that the object was not moving. Thus, I require at least 3 or more consecutive 'waiting' conditions, before I can be sure the object was indeed not moving.

I would like to detect these waiting positions and label them accordingly in a new column.

```
Example :
                    x         y
timestamp                       
2023-07-01 00:00:00   1         5
2023-07-01 00:01:00   2         6
2023-07-01 00:02:00   3         7
2023-07-01 00:03:00   4         8
2023-07-01 00:04:00   4         8
2023-07-01 00:05:00   5         9
2023-07-01 00:06:00   6         9
2023-07-01 00:07:00   7        10
2023-07-01 00:08:00   7        10
2023-07-01 00:09:00   7        10
2023-07-01 00:10:00   7        10
2023-07-01 00:11:00   8        11
2023-07-01 00:12:00   9        11
```

To compute the distance, I already shifted the dataframe by 1, and caluclate the distance:

```
                    x         y  distance  
timestamp                                                    
2023-07-01 00:00:00   1         5       NaN   
2023-07-01 00:01:00   2         6  1.414214    
2023-07-01 00:02:00   3         7  1.414214   
2023-07-01 00:03:00   4         8  1.414214   
2023-07-01 00:04:00   4         8  0.000000   
2023-07-01 00:05:00   5         9  1.414214  
2023-07-01 00:06:00   6         9  1.000000   
2023-07-01 00:07:00   7        10  1.414214   
2023-07-01 00:08:00   7        10  0.000000   
2023-07-01 00:09:00   7        10  0.000000   
2023-07-01 00:10:00   7        10  0.000000   
2023-07-01 00:11:00   8        11  1.414214   
2023-07-01 00:12:00   9        11  1.000000
```

Now, assume if the distance is lower than 1, it could potentially be a waiting position:

```
                    x         y  distance  condition_fulfilled  
timestamp                                                    
2023-07-01 00:00:00   1         5       NaN    NaN    
2023-07-01 00:01:00   2         6  1.414214    False    
2023-07-01 00:02:00   3         7  1.414214    False    
2023-07-01 00:03:00   4         8  1.414214    False    
2023-07-01 00:04:00   4         8  0.000000    True   
2023-07-01 00:05:00   5         9  1.414214    False   
2023-07-01 00:06:00   6         9  1.000000    False   
2023-07-01 00:07:00   7        10  1.414214    False   
2023-07-01 00:08:00   7        10  0.000000    True   
2023-07-01 00:09:00   7        10  0.000000    True   
2023-07-01 00:10:00   7        10  0.000000    True    
2023-07-01 00:11:00   8        11  1.414214    False    
2023-07-01 00:12:00   9        11  1.000000    False
```

Since I require at least 3 consecutive fulfilled condtions, the expected output would be:

```
                    x         y  distance    status  
timestamp                                                    
2023-07-01 00:00:00   1         5       NaN    moving    
2023-07-01 00:01:00   2         6  1.414214    moving    
2023-07-01 00:02:00   3         7  1.414214    moving    
2023-07-01 00:03:00   4         8  1.414214    moving    
2023-07-01 00:04:00   4         8  0.000000    moving   
2023-07-01 00:05:00   5         9  1.414214    moving   
2023-07-01 00:06:00   6         9  1.000000    moving   
2023-07-01 00:07:00   7        10  1.414214    moving   
2023-07-01 00:08:00   7        10  0.000000    waiting   
2023-07-01 00:09:00   7        10  0.000000    waiting   
2023-07-01 00:10:00   7        10  0.000000    waiting    
2023-07-01 00:11:00   8        11  1.414214    moving    
2023-07-01 00:12:00   9        11  1.000000    moving
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# fill the first NaN
df['condition_fulfilled'] = df['condition_fulfilled'].bfill()

tmp = (df['condition_fulfilled'] != df['condition_fulfilled'].shift()).cumsum()
df['status'] = df.groupby(tmp)['condition_fulfilled'].transform(lambda x: 'waiting' if x.all() and len(x) >= 3 else 'moving')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     x   y  distance  condition_fulfilled   status
timestamp                                                         
2023-07-01 00:00:00  1   5       NaN                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:01:00  2   6  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:02:00  3   7  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:03:00  4   8  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:04:00  4   8  0.000000                 True   moving
2023-07-01 00:05:00  5   9  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:06:00  6   9  1.000000                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:07:00  7  10  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:08:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:09:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:10:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:11:00  8  11  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:12:00  9  11  1.000000                False   moving
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['status'] = (df.groupby(['distance', df['condition_fulfilled'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()])
                   ['distance'].transform('size').eq(3).astype(bool))
df['status'] = np.where(df['status'], 'waiting', 'moving')
```

Output is:

```
                     x   y  distance  condition_fulfilled   status
timestamp                                                         
2023-07-01 00:00:00  1   5       NaN                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:01:00  2   6  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:02:00  3   7  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:03:00  4   8  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:04:00  4   8  0.000000                 True   moving
2023-07-01 00:05:00  5   9  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:06:00  6   9  1.000000                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:07:00  7  10  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:08:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:09:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:10:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:11:00  8  11  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:12:00  9  11  1.000000                False   moving
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
N = 3

df['condition_fulfilled'] = df['condition_fulfilled'].fillna(False)

df['status'] = np.where(
                df.groupby((~df['condition_fulfilled']).cumsum())
                  .transform('size').ge(N+1)
                & df['condition_fulfilled'],
                  'waiting', 'moving'
                )
```

Output:

```
                     x   y  distance  condition_fulfilled   status
timestamp                                                         
2023-07-01 00:00:00  1   5       NaN                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:01:00  2   6  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:02:00  3   7  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:03:00  4   8  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:04:00  4   8  0.000000                 True   moving
2023-07-01 00:05:00  5   9  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:06:00  6   9  1.000000                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:07:00  7  10  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:08:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:09:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:10:00  7  10  0.000000                 True  waiting
2023-07-01 00:11:00  8  11  1.414214                False   moving
2023-07-01 00:12:00  9  11  1.000000                False   moving
```